AWS ElastiCache JSON.ARRAPPEND multi services support
In AWS, several services might append to the same array (with the same key) simultaneously. The order in this array is not critical.
Is it possible that some of the events will not be inserted at all (and no error will be return)? Is it mandatory in this case to use distributed lock?
